# Reference that lists available JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, browser, client-side

I'm aware of things like `onchange`, `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` but is there a good reference somewhere that lists all of them complete with possibly a list of the elements that they cover?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

W3Schools seems to have a good Javascript events reference: [HTML DOM Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Answer (score 11):

Quirksmode has a nice [event-compatibility table](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) and an [introduction](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty good JavaScript event reference with the elements they are for:
[JavaScript Tutorial >> JavaScript Events](http://www.globalguideline.com/JavaScript_Guide/Java_Script_Events.php)

Answer (score 4):

This [Javascript Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/javascript-cheat-sheet/) has a complete list of of event handlers. Nearly all of them can be used on any html element except for one or two.

If you want to use a lightweight javascript library, [DOMAssistant](http://www.domassistant.com/) is very lightweight and allows you to add events to elements very easily. Like so:

```
$("#navigation a").addEvent("click", myFunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be working with events (setting custom functions and event handlers), then I'd recommend checking out the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). It makes [event binding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) so much easier than doing it by hand.